# i want to change the background of the card div using PHP

Tags: php, css

I used the for loop to get the data dynamically from the database and displayed ,Now  I have to display those cards in different colors using Php No javascript is needed

```
<div class="row gutter-xs">
     <?php
     foreach($dispcnt as $object)
     {
        ?><div  class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="card bg-info"> // card 
            <div class="card-values">
              <div class="p-x">
                <small><?php echo $object->qa;?> </small>
                <h3 class="card-title-l"><?php echo  $object->cnt;?> Counts</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
     </div> // code of card ends here
     <?php }?>
     </div>
```

I want to change the color of the cards in PHP [image: Current page]

I am excepting the cards to look like this [image: output needed]

Comment: You can, using a simple if statement. I know it works, but don't put PHP functions and keywords in CAPS.

Comment: why don't you put the class in each of `$dispcnt`'s items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution A with CSS only

Actually, you don't need any PHP to do that, you could do it only with some CSS rules with the help of the `:nth-child()` selector.

Here's a little snippet for demo if you have 4 colors always repeating:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  width: 10em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .5em;
  color: white;
  background: #0298cf;
}

.card:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background: #0298cf;
}

.card:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: #9b479f;
}

.card:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background: #4e484e;
}

.card:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: #f70d1a;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 1</small>
        <h3>1 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 2</small>
        <h3>2 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 3</small>
        <h3>3 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 4</small>
        <h3>4 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 5</small>
        <h3>5 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 6</small>
        <h3>6 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 7</small>
        <h3>7 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 8</small>
        <h3>8 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="card bg-info">
    <div class="card-values">
      <div class="p-x">
        <small>Small 9</small>
        <h3>9 Counts</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

If you want 6 colors then you would replace `4n` by `6n` and add the 2 other colors.

In your case, you'll have to put it on the first `<div>` which is in the loop, so the div directly child of the row:

```css
.row > :nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background: #0298cf;
}

.row > :nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background: #9b479f;
}

.row > :nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background: #4e484e;
}

.row > :nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background: #f70d1a;
}
```

### Solution B with PHP to generate a CSS class

By the way, your PHP should be in lowercase. You could also print a color class and increment it like this:

```php
<div class="row gutter-XS">
<?php
$color = 1;
foreach ($dispcnt as $object) {
    $color_class = "bg-color-$color";
    if ($color < 4) {
        $color++;
    } else {
        $color = 1;
    }
?>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="card <?php echo $color_class; ?>">
            <div class="card-values">
                <div class="p-x">
                    <small><?php echo $object->QA; ?></small>
                    <h3 class="card-title-l"><?php echo $object->CNT; ?> Counts</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

You'll then have the possibility to have CSS rules such as:

```css
.card.bg-color-1 {
  background: #0298cf;
}

.card.bg-color-2 {
  background: #9b479f;
}

.card.bg-color-3 {
  background: #4e484e;
}

.card.bg-color-4 {
  background: #f70d1a;
}
```

Comment: I tried the part b but the color is not showing up

Comment: @Shadywolf21 : I updated my solution A, because I forgot that I had simplified the HTML for the snippet example. In your case, the `:nth-child()` selector has to be used on the `<div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">` as it's this one looping.

Comment: @Shadywolf21 : 2nd update => I made a stupid error: I was generating the class `bg-color-x` and in the CSS I wrote `.card.color-x` instead of `.card.bg-color-x`. It should work now.

Comment: Yes the 2nd Update works now Thanks ..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a PHP-only solution. Just set an array with the desired colors and use modulo to cycle through them as you iterate over the cards. Put a `style` attribute on the card to set the `background` color.

```
<div class="row gutter-XS">
     <?php
  $colors = [
'#0298cf',
'#9b479f',
'#4e484e',
'#f70d1a',
];
$count = count($colors);
$i = 0; // increment this counter at the end of the foreach loop
  foreach ($dispcnt as $object)
     {
        ?><div  class="col-xs-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="card BG-info" style="background:<?php echo $colors[($i % $count)]; ?>"> <!-- card -->
            <div class="card-values">
              <div class="p-x">
                <small><?php echo $object->QA;?> </small>
                <h3 class="card-title-l"><?php echo  $object->CNT;?> Counts</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
     </div> <!-- code of card ends here -->
     <?php $i++;}?>
     </div>
```

Comment: I also thought about the idea of the array of colors but then I thought about the concept of separating the design rules from the HTML, so I try to avoid using the `style` attribute. By the way, no need to increment `$i` at the end of the loop. Do it directly in your modulo since `$i++` returns the value of `$i` and then increments it.

Comment: @PatrickJanser I agree it is generally better to separate design from content markup, just wanted to show how it could be done only in PHP.  Good point about the behavior of `$i++`